# Center Elements on Screen while Keeping Responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out a way to position the **brown chevrons** such that as the it **vertically** stays at the **center** of the screen as the user scrolls but does't cut into either the header image or footer.

I know this can be solved with `position: absolute`, but I want to keep Bootstrap's responsiveness. How do I go about doing that?

Header
[image]

Footer
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery scrollTop to detect when you are at the top or bottom of the window, and then toggle different css classes for the element at different scrollpoints.

I also think you are looking for position "fixed" as opposed to "absolute".

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
        $('selection').toggleClass("your-class");
    } else {
        $('selection').toggleClass("your-class);
    }
})

.your-class {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
selection {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top:50%;
}
```

Comment: No problem. That's why we're here.